# C# MySQL Connector

Tags: c#, mysql

Should I build my own wrapper class for MySQL or should I use download one of the installable MySQL addins for Visual Studio to help?

My App is pretty simple, but I'm also new to C#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL provides .NET conector for C#.
See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)!

You can use it in very simple projects. [Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/puranindia/81/Default.aspx) is an example of using it with ADO.NET with ODBC driver and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html) how to use it directly.

For more complex projects I strongly suggest to use some OR mappers that supports MySQL like [SubSonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/) or [BLToolkit](http://bltoolkit.net/).

Comment: This isn't an example of the .NET MySQL Connector, it is an example of using the ODBC connector.  I want to connect natively from .NET, not through an ODBC connector.

Comment: So try this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials.html and especially this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-intro.html